# Unable to ping default gateway in guest vm (QEMU/KVM) after upgrading Linux kernel to 4.11

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have a host Ubuntu16.04 and I used `QEMU/KVM` (3.0.0) to create a Windows guest VM, and networking went smoothly. But I need to enable nested virtualization so **I upgraded Linux kernel version to 4.11** (4.11.2-041102-generic), after doing that, the guest VM which runs on KVM cannot reach the host via network, cannot ping default gateway either.

Here is the example:
guest vm ip: 192.168.136.9
br2: 192.168.136.253

```
br2   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:0e:d5:c7:0c:e5  
      inet addr:192.168.136.253  Bcast:192.168.136.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::320e:d5ff:fec7:ce5/64 Scope:Link
      ......
```

This is the network setting of my guest VM:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:04:01:d6'/>
  <source bridge='br2'/>
  <model type='e1000'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

And set the guest VM's IP as 192.168.136.9, set gateway as 192.168.136.253:
[image]

But, when I tried to ping the gateway in the guest vm `ping 192.168.136.253`, it shows:

> Reply from 192.168.136.9: Destination host unreachable.

From host, I can't ping 192.168.136.9 either.

**I don't know how to solve this problem and why. Any help is appreciated!**

Below is what I checked before asking this question:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward -> 1
$ vim /etc/sysctl.conf -> net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
$ systemctl status libvirtd -> active (running)
$ systemctl status libvirt-bin -> active (running)
```

Env:
Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Linux kernel 4.11.2-041102-generic
QEMU 3.0.0
Libvirtd 1.3.1
Virt-manager 1.3.2

**========== Update ==========**

I solved this problem by creating another new vm `virt-install ... --network network=default`, this time it runs perfectly, it can ping to default gateway and host, I `meld` their config files found that they have different interface type:

```
<interface type='network'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:88:d1:87'/>
  <source network='default'/>
  <model type='rtl8139'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

It works now anyway, but I modified the older vm's interface type to network, still doesn't work, weird.